# Can we connect more than 10 devices with wi-fi hot-spot in Android

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, real-time-data

I am working on project push to talk over wifi hotspot or wifi direct in real time, but I am unable to connect more than 10 devices through one hotspot as android given this limitation.
but I want to connect 40 - 50 devices, so can anyone tell me that how can I connect with multiple devices, So that one message can be delivered on all 50 devices in real time from one device without any router or additional hardware.

Comment: There are H/W limitations also to support those many connections in mobile hotspot.

Comment: @vishalm Is there any way to connect multiple devices(more than 10) with one mobile device.

Comment: @vishalm Can you mention or hint these H/W limitations that you said in your comment? I would like to know them.

Comment: @Firelord Memory restrictions on wifi HW could also prevent supporting large number of devices. There may be other reasons, but I don't know them.

Comment: @Ankit Did you came across any solution for your problem.?

Comment: No I could not get solution which I want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

USING HOTSPOT IN THE HOUSE WITH MORE THAN 10 DEVICES

I've been searching for an answer to that for a little while. I found something that works with a little money what I end up using was some old devices that I had laying around the house. What you need is two items you need a repeater, and also an old router. if you have to use a repeater alone, it uses it in bridge mode so therefore it will not be assigning new IP addresses. The IP address are assigned by the phone in that case, so therefore you will reach its limit. on top of that, the repeater itself will take away one of the spots on your phone as one of the 10 devices. but I did is the following. I use the repeater which has a ethernet out. connected my phone to the repeater. Then I plugged in my old router into the repeater routers WAN port and connected it with a CAT5 cable to the repeater.   Placed the old router into DHCP mode bring it with a new network name.  Then connected all the devices to the old router, and none of them show up on the repeater or on the phones hotspot.   Basically you're creating a subnet I guess.  Works great and honestly for low bandwidth devices it runs fine, the speed test was almost the same as off of the repeater itself.  If anything, use the high priorioty/bandwidth devices onto the hotspot directly, and then use the repeater/router for the low bandwidth stuff (smart speakers/plugs/lights)

also another tip I can say. Right now my wireless carrier gives me unlimited hotspot to all of my phones. I have multiple phones that come in and out of the house. So what I have done is place all the phones with the same exact SSID for the hotspot, and also the same exact password. So therefore the Wi-Fi repeater will join so whichever phone is in the house.  Personally this has been a great replacement for internet in my house since my demand for internet is not that high. And if you have unlimited internet I guess you can use this even as a replacement for home internet. also this way it distributes the Hotspot data usage to all the different phone.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a tall order considering the limitations are more to do with the WiFi components than the OS. The only possible approach I see would be to dynamically connect/disconnect the WiFi connections and cycle through each of your 50 connections. Doing that in a timely fashion and without killing the battery in the process will probably be quite challenging.

Comment: But I want to connect all devices simultaneously so that I can    pass message to all in real time.